# Rig deformation problem

Tags: mesh, rigging

My rig is not bending the meshes legs correctly and stretches the leg and arm weirdly

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please upload your .blend file to be able to help you

Comment: uploaded the .blend file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I added a subsurf after the armature modifier, turned on the "preserve volume" option, turned on the "edit mode visibility" buttons and tweaked the weight values: in the central joint edge loop 0.5/0.5, then 0.75/0.25, then 0.95/0.05.

In the arms there is not enough geometry to get smooth bends, you'll have to add some edge loops.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean on the weight values part could you simplify it a bit for me

Comment: The armature modifier establishes a relationship between a bone of the rig and a vertex group of the mesh which have the same exact name. If a vertex belongs to a vertex group only, it will move rigidly with the bone movement; if it belongs to two (or more) vertex group, it will move in a proportional way, according to his weight. To have smooth joints it's common to select the central edge loop and assign to all vertex a weight of 0.5 (50% of action) to both vertex groups related to the two bones of the joints, so that their movements will be influenced by the movement of both bones.

Comment: In the picture you can see that an edge loop close to the central one is selected. In the "N" propeties panel you can read that the selected vertex has a weight of 0.250 related to the "Leg_bottom.L" bone, and a weight of 0.750 related to the "Leg:Top.L" bone. This means that this vertex will be influenced by movements of both bones: 25% from "Leg_bottom.L bone", 75% from "Leg_Top.L" bone movements.